# how to find the string element that match with string only from starting?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application i want display the suggestion names based on the character that user types in that input box. I get the user input using keyup event and i have a array of names from that i want to select the names that matches with the user input only from the starting letters. For Example if the user types A the suggestion show the name start with A,(For Ro-Root Valuation) How to do this?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 var usernames = ["Abisi","Bentaven", "Root Valuation", "Leidos Health",  "Visante",  "vendor1",  "yest1", "example"];

    var displayname = [];

    $('#input-text').keyup(function(event){

        var $textValue = $(this).val();
        jQuery.each( usernames,function( i, val ) {
            *** find that matching name ***
               if($textValue == val){
                   displayname.push(val);

               }
            });

    });
```

Comment: could try with `val.indexOf($textValue) === 0`  [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: use jQuery filter... http://api.jquery.com/filter/ or grep.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/bqkobo79/1/

```
var length= $textValue.length;
displayname=jQuery.grep(usernames, function( element, i ) {
if(element.toLowerCase().substr(0,length)===$textValue.toLowerCase())
    return element;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for response Its work only for first letter when i type 2 character like vi i get all the names with  starts with v.

Comment: I don't think so, as If you look in the fiddle, i tried with `vi` as input value, it returns only Visante, considering the array you have shared..

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the text typed matches the name:

```
$textValue = $textValue.toLowerCase();
val = val.toLowerCase();
var is_matched = ($textValue.substr(0, ($textValue.length)) == val.substr(0, ($textValue.length)))
```

To make sure that you get suggestions you need to send after checking if it is true:

```
if (is_matched == true) {
    displayname.push(val);
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Final Code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var usernames = ["Abisi","Bentaven", "Root Valuation", "Leidos Health",  "Visante",  "vendor1",  "yest1", "example"];

var displayname = [];
$('#input-text').keyup(function (event) {

var $textValue = $(this).val();
jQuery.each(usernames, function (i, val) {
    $textValue = $textValue.toLowerCase();
    val = val.toLowerCase();
    var is_matched = ($textValue.substr(0, ($textValue.length)) == val.substr(0, ($textValue.length)))
    if (is_matched == true) {
        displayname.push(val);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});

});
```

Comment: Thanks for response Its work only for first letter when i type 2 charactes like vi i get all the names with  starts with v.

Answer (score 0):

[`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) can tell you if a string contain another string and the index of the first match of that substring.

`"Abisi".indexOf("A") == 0`

In your case you can use it to retrieve a set of strings that start with the value of the text input

```js
var usernames = ["Abisi","Bentaven", "Root Valuation", "Leidos Health",  "Visante",  "vendor1",  "yest1", "example"];

var displayname = [];

$('#input-text').keyup(function(event){
    var $textValue = $(this).val();
    displayname = [];
    
    if ($textValue.length > 0){
        jQuery.each( usernames,function( i, val ) {
            if(val.indexOf($textValue) === 0){
                displayname.push(val);
            }
        });
    }

    console.log(displayname);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input-text"/>
```